# problem with css

Tags: html, css

what is wrong in this code? css is not working

```
<style type="text/css">
    .mail a:link {
        color: grey;
    }

   .mail a:visited {
        color: grey;
    }

   .mail a:hover {
        color: white;
    }
</style>

<a class="mail" href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu">E-mail: suporte@web.pt</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your css styles apply to anchor elements that are descendants of .mail and not the anchor elements with class name mail.

Change the style definitions to as below:

```
<style type="text/css">     
    a.mail:link {         
        color: grey;     
    }     

    a.mail:visited {         
        color: grey;     
    }     

    a.mail:hover {         
        color: white;     
    }   
</style>
```

Comment: Tangential Tip: it's more efficient to just use .mail (http://moorer.me/jP97GR).  Similarly, you can omit :link for unvisited links.

Answer (score 3):

'a' is not a descendent of .mail.

Try a.mail